# doPostback() not refreshing some elements on page correctly

Tags: javascript, vb.net, postback, dopostback

Having the following problem:

I have an HTML button which causes a __doPostBack(button.ClientID,'texthere').

```
Dim button As HtmlButton
button = CType(Me.btnButton, HtmlButton)
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "__doPostBack('" & btnButton.ClientID & "', 'btnBBHistory');return false;")
```

In my page_load I have the following:

```
Dim control_postback = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")
    If control_postback = "texthere"
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Script", "ShowWindow();", 
    End If
```

The ShowWindow(); javascript function is displayed using showModalDialog.

```
  Dim s As New StringBuilder
        s.Append("<script type=""text/javaScript"">")
        s.Append("function ShowWindow() {" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        '  s.Append("var result = window.showModalDialog('" & url & "','','dialogWidth:1200px;dialogHeight:450px;resizable:yes');" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("var result = window.showModalDialog('" & url & "','','dialogWidth:1100px;dialogHeight:500px;resizable:yes;help:no;');" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("if (result) { " & ControlChars.CrLf)
        ' s.Append("document.getElementById('" & lblwhatever.ClientID & "').innerHTML=result.fullline;" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("if (result.text.length || result.quantity.length) { " & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("document.getElementById('" & txtwhatever.ClientID & "').value=result.text.concat(result.quantity);" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("document.getElementById('" & txtqty.ClientID & "').value=result.quantity;" & ControlChars.CrLf)

        s.Append("__doPostBack()" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("}" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("}" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("return false;" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("}" & ControlChars.CrLf)
        s.Append("</script>")
        If Not ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ShowWindow") Then
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "ShowWindow", s.ToString())
        End If
```

This all works fine and the dialog box with the generated URL is displayed. However, on the originating webpage (the one where the button is initially clicked to produce this dialog box), there is an image (.djvu format). Whenever my code is run, the originating page is refreshed because of the __doPostBack() but in certain version of IE (IE8 and 9 so far) the image does not reload. Is there a chance that the showModalDialog is preventing any further rendering of the page in the background on these versions of IE or that the doPostBack() is not actually doing a complete postback in some way and the image is breaking?

Thanks for any help you might be able to give

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I needed to use window.open instead of showmodaldialog as when using showmodaldialog, the parent/calling page was (i believe) pausing/halting/breaking execution of the parent page until the child page was closed